# How to fix the warning when I convert NIFTI to AFNI

Tags: matlab

I use afni command to convert NIFTI file to AFNI file, the command  shows as follows:

```
 3dcopy structural.nii structural+orig
 ++ 3dcopy: AFNI version=AFNI_17.0.02 (Jan 19 2017) [64-bit]
 *+ WARNING: NO spatial transform (neither qform nor sform), in NIfTI file 'structural.nii'
```

I search online but still cannot find an effective way to solve the problem of the warning and get the right afni file. Can anyone give me a help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This question requires more detail from the SO. please run the command including the `-verb` switch to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not actually related to matlab and as I mentioned in the comment, you should provide more details in your question. You can run the same command including the switch `-verb` to get more detail.

In the meanwhile, it seems you are using `3dcopy` to perform the conversion. As mentioned by documents the warning message should not be important and can be ignored.

However, I suspect that the header (including the transformation) is not being copied during the previous step hence the warning.

So you need also to mention the step before using the `3dcopy` in the question.

---

In case you want suppress the warnings in Matlab you can try:

```
warning('off','all')
```

To suppress all the warnings. To stop specific warnings you need to find the `id` of that warning. There is a well-documented piece [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/suppress-warnings.html).

Comment: If there is warning, that means something is wrong there. I do not think turn off warning is the right choice.

Comment: With your question and the given amount of information, it looks like you wanted to hide the warning, (as you say "remove" it). If you want to find the error you should provide proper information. A specific warning msg it would be really hard to get to the bottom of the issue.

Comment: I modified the question!